# Git Squashing, Rebase

Tags: git

I have my git history log as:

- Commit 4 - HEAD
- Commit 3
- Commit 2
- Commit 1

I want to squash Commit 2,3 into one commit, so that it shoud look like:

- Commit 4 - HEAD
- Commit 3, 2  - Squashed together
- Commit 1

As per my understanding, rebase/squashing work from current commit to HEAD. I cant just pick commit between.

Please let me know if this is a feasible option, if so, please help with git command.

Thank you

Comment: What does HEAD mean in your question? Perhaps replacing it with "master" or "base" would make it clearer. HEAD has a very specific meaning in git (i.e. currently checked out commit) and it seems like it means something else in your question.

Comment: @Frax in my understanding HEAD is the current commit right?

Comment: Yes, HEAD is the current commit. So it's a bit confusing when you say separately "Current" and "HEAD" - and so it's pretty unclear what is the order of the commits.

Comment: @jainank do you understand the comment?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, fixed the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use the interactive option of rebase.  `git rebase -i <sha for commit 1>`, this will open a text editor with the list of your commits like so:

```
pick Commit 2
pick Commit 3
pick Commit 4
```

Change the pick for commit 3 to be `s` or `squash`.  Save and exit from the editor.  Git will reapply the commits combining Commit 3 into Commit 2. (It will also allow you to adjust the commit message).

Comment: `git rebase -i HEAD`, taken literally, doesn't make sense (i.e. does nothing). I know you took this name from the question, but please at least make it clear what it means here.

Comment: @frax thanks, i wrote that up without really thinking about it.

Comment: Hmm, I read more carefully into your answer and it seems like the order is upside down, assuming that commit 4 is the newest (and so you need to squash 3 into 2, not the other way around).

Comment: They might be but the editor does explain things and using interactive rebase is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: The point of SO is to provide good answers for anyone with the same question. "That's enough for OP to solve the problem" is not a valid justification for not fixing the answer. Submitted the edit suggestion.

Comment: @frax that wasn't what I meant but no worries.  Approved the edit suggestion.